# Worker assignment for a product servicing or Return back the repaired product

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, numpy

Have a dataset which contains a list of works, a list of customer and product room locations.
Workers have to go and pick the products from the customer location to the product room, where the item will undergo servicing-(**task1**).
After this, the product has to return back to the customer location-(**task2**).

Considering both worker and customer location are known in (latitude, longitude).
**How can we assign the tasks (say 10:30 am -11:30 am) efficiently?**

**SQL Tables:**
Table 1 - Worker:
`workerId / lat / longt / availability / dateoflogin`

Table 2 - Customer:
`custmerId/ Address/ customer_lat/ customer_longt/ date/ timeslot`

**Constraints:**

- There is no working hours limit
- If the worker is available, we get availability as 1, else 0 in Table 1.
- The travelling distance of the worker is maximum 10 Km (straight line). Speed is not considered in this assignment.
- Only one item at a time is picked and given to product room or return back from product room to customer.

I tried grouping in my way with respect to minimum distance but the same worker is getting more than one job at same time. I am looking for a solution like below using python. I tried pandas grouping. it is giving more than one work for a worker

```
Slno   │ Customer id │      worker id │   Distance │
╞══════╪═════════════╪════════════════╪════════════╡
 111   │          219│          11272 │   5.74435  │
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to give us samples of your two tables ? (csv format for instance)

Comment: I am not able to upload csv files.can u guide how to upload?

Comment: you cannot, but check how to make a reproducible examples here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3941704 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/3941704

Comment: <pre>13430 21-03-2016 17:18 148 22-03-2016 4 22-03-2016 08:00 -54 28.697904 77.218806 81 28.697904 77.218806 12806 1074 13345 1 0 0 NULL 3 1 1 3 0 NULL NULL 1 9033 5 NULL 5 5 NULL NULL NULL 0 125 NULL              
13431 21-03-2016 17:21 148 22-03-2016 4 22-03-2016 08:00 BE-4  28.70681 77.15507 12807 1074 13346 1 0 0 NULL 3 12 0 3 0 NULL NULL 1 8125 5 8228 5 5 NULL NULL NULL 0 250 NULL

Comment: put your data in the question (edit it) and give the headers.